# Is it possible to add an add-in icon in OWA's "easy-access" add-in toolbar?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin

Hello Outlook/Microsoft Team,

I would like to ask if there is a way to add our add-in icon to the "easy-access-toolbar" as shown in the image below. This toolbar (of outlook add-ins) is shown whenever you are reading email via the browser. Unfortunately, I could not find any guide or documentation on how to add a custom icon in this list.

After some investigations, I found that only add-ins from the market are added to this. Is my understanding correct? Or can a domain admin set this up? Or does this require a manifest entry?

Our outlook add-in is used exclusively by "enterprise" accounts. Thus, we did not deem it necessary to publish with the add-in store.

Thank you for your support and understanding.

[image: strong text]

Comment: You can pin an add-in so it's easily available when you're composing an email message using these steps:-
1)Select Settings Settings > View all Outlook settings > Mail > Customize actions.
2)Select the check box for the add-in that you want to see when you’re composing a message.
Please follow this doc for further understanding :- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-add-ins-in-outlook-com-a5672109-e4f3-4119-abea-72323e9653cf

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thank you very much for your quick and prompt response. The next question I have though, is if there is a way for a domain admin to do this for everyone unde their domain.

Comment: We have the work item in our backlog to pin admin add-ins in the ribbon, similar to self-installed add-ins. This feature is high on our priority and its currently being worked upon

Comment: Thank you again for that very quick response. Any chance we can track the progress on this or any estimated date of release? A lot of our end users look forward and love the possibility of having this for their environments. Thank you again.

Comment: We are tracking this work item internally and we will update this thread when we have updates. Unfortunately, we cannot share any publicly available information on this work item progress

Comment: We really appreciate your feedback and fast responses. Please do update this thread if you have it supported. That would be awesome. Thank you @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT.

Comment: Do we have any update on this @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT? Thank you.

Comment: The latest change in the addin location and the inability of an admin to pin addin icons for everyone in the organization, is causing a user experience issues for a lot of our users. Is there any update as to when the admin-level icon-pinning mechanism will be released? Thank you.